# Where is a good collection of freely licensed instrument .wav samples?

Tags: iphone, resources, wav

I require full samples for a variety of instruments. One such site that provides this resource (http://theremin.music.uiowa.edu/MIS.html) is good, but there aren't enough non-classical instruments (e.g. steel guitar, drums).

I need a different resource that provides instrument samples such as ones the MIDI specification supports.

Side note: I only require middle C samples for each instrument.

Comment: i think what you are looking for is called a "soundfont"; try http://www.google.com/search?hl=en&source=hp&q=free+soundfont&aq=f&oq=&aqi=g10

Comment: @close-monkeys: please do not close this question. This is a totally legitimate question about where to find audio resources for audio programming. I am personally interested in the answers. Thank you.

Comment: Yeah there are sondfonts made specifically to be used with the General MIDI spec. Some huge, but some reasonable in size. However, all the ones I know of are multisampled--up-pitching a middle C will quickly lead to aliasing.

Comment: @Steven: a soundfont is really only one type of audio sample file, and it's actually not a very good choice for what the asker needs, since the file structure is relatively complex (it contains articulation information as well as the raw sample data) and an SF2 file usually contains more than one raw audio file (for covering different note ranges).

Comment: This seems program-related to me. I assume the closers are fixated on your first statement.

Comment: @Nosredna: I feel like a vampire who just found a likely victim and then noticed that she already had two holes in her neck. :)

Comment: Can I ask why you think you need just middle C?

Comment: @MusiGenesis, we do seem to land on the same questions, don't we?

Comment: @Nosredna: I see "wav" or "audio" and I know it's bound to be more interesting than "how do I sort a List<T>?" :)

Comment: If http://stackoverflow.com/questions/139944/where-can-one-find-free-software-icons-images can exist, I would assume this thread should be allowed.

Comment: I require middle-C because that makes things memory efficient when you create a "wavetable" that maps the resources you need (instead of using 88 keys on a grand piano, you just use 1). OpenAL does the rest for you. But like Nosredna said there is a possibility of aliasing, esp. with distorted sounds. So far with piano, though, the quality has been good enough.

Comment: If it's good enough for your purposes, that's fine. Anything that has high harmonics will alias. Only you can decide how much aliasing is acceptable.

Answer (score 3):

One thing you could try is to search around for free Reason Refills, and also look for Refill Unpackers to get at the samples contained within the refill. Just make sure that you are allowed to do so under the terms of the refill license.

Also, check out [PrimeLoops](http://www.primeloops.com/) and [Freesound](http://www.freesound.org/)

Answer (score 1):

[Soundsnap](http://www.soundsnap.com/) lets you download 5 royalty free sounds a month with the free account, and they have a wide selection of instrument audio clips.

Answer (score 1):

I got my first collection of sounds at Maz Sound Tools. Longer ago than I care to imagine. Glad Maz is still there. (You'll have to check the license.)

http://www.maz-sound.com/

See samples & sounds / free sounds

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried [www.freesound.org](http://www.freesound.org/) ? All Creative Commons licences.

The collection from the University of Iowa that you linked to is a very high quality and I assume it took a long time to collect all of those samples, edit them and prepare them for distribution.

Answer (score 1):

I got some that were royalty free for super cheap, all of the .wav sound samples were hi quality like the strings, drums, piano, ect.. and they work both on my akai mpc and propellerhead reason. I highly recommend this guy http://stores.ebay.com/Platinum-Sound-Studio

I also think he has a website that has a bunch of great tutorials and stuff for audio production its http://www.audioproducer.org I will check out the refills, thanks for sharing the links! :)

Answer (score 0):

Alas, I don't think there's an easy no-brainer way to give you exactly the instruments you want.

I think if you have a finished set of MIDI songs from someone else and want to play it as intended, you should hunt for a MIDI player that you can license or use from your app, one which supports the banks etc used by the songs - whether the instruments are .wav or synth. That would be the quickest way, but least control. (No, I don't know if such music players exist. Most seem to sample the songs and play .mp3.)

But it sounds like you want to pick out the instruments to use for each song, and that they should be decent quality .wav? Well, you could try a few SoundFonts and pick out the instruments that map well onto the song perhaps.

Hunting separate instruments on the Web will give you gray hairs I think. Quality is very uneven and might need to be resampled, tested, etc. Not to mention all the unnecessary listening and downloading.

Reason Refills (sound-packs) are usually excellent and well-rounded. You can pick loose samples from different Refills, but if you have Reason you can import the MIDI and assign instruments to hear how the instrument-sets will work before settling on a set of .wavs. There's already a ton of quality classical, pop/rock instrument Refills in Reason, so there might not even be a need to try add-on Refills.

Being unfamiliar with picking out samples from SoundFonts, I think the Reason method will give you more control over quality.